# apply border radius to font awesome fa-window-close-o

Tags: font-awesome

I am using fa `fa-window-close-o` icon. For minimizing and maximize the divs on my html i have used `minus-square` and `plus-square`. These both icons are rounded but `fa-window-close-o` is not. is there any way i can apply a border radius to this icon ?

`window-close-o` icon was very thick so i changed it a thin using 
`-webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;` but now there is not any radius option to set it .